# C# Code/Expression to find which range a certain value falls within --

Tags: c#, lambda, aggregate-functions, boolean-expression

I will just explain in brief what I have.

I have a list of configuration data like this --
[image]

Now I am trying to write code to find out which set/config a certain user falls, based upon his purchase sales amount. for eg. if he has made a sale of 23000 bucks he becomes a G01 grade salesguy. If he made 51000 bucks, he is G04 grade. If he made sale of 29000 bucks he would be G02 grade. Or if he made 71000 he is obviously G05 grade. Like that. To explain my use-case.

The code/logic I wrote was something like -

```
public JsonResult CustomerGradeByID([FromBody]decimal saleAmt)
{
    try
    {
        var cGrade = CustomerGrade(Convert.ToDecimal(saleAmt));
        return Json(cGrade);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        return Json(exp.GetBaseException());
    }
}
protected string CustomerGrade(decimal salesTot)
{
    try
    {
        var grades = _appDbContext.CustomerGrades.ToList();
        CustomerGrade cg = grades.Aggregate((a, b) => a.grade_minsaleamount < salesTot && salesTot < b.grade_minsaleamount ? a : b);
        var gdName = cg.grade_name.ToString();
        return gdName;
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
}
```

Don't worry about _appdbcontext and all that I am just fetching and populating from my db where that table is stored. Apparently the logic for 'CustomerGrade' is wrong. Because it is giving me all kinds of haywire results. For 33000 bucks sale it gives G01, for 61000 bucks it gives G04 and similar other all kinds of erroneous outputs. I tried using lambda aggregate. But seems it is incorrect.

Can you help me perfect this logic please? A bulletproof logic for this scenario? It would be hugely helpful for me!
Thanks to all,

This is my actual set of data --

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `grade_minsaleamount` are unique, you can just order the list and use `FirstOrDefault` i guess, it can all be done on the DB

```
var result = _appDbContext.CustomerGrades
                          .OrderBy(x => x.grade_minsaleamount)
                          .FirstOrDefault(x => salesTot >= x.grade_minsaleamount);

// Sanity check for null
if(result != null)
{
   // found!
   Debug.WriteLine(result.Name);
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#definition)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

[Enumerable.OrderBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order.

## Update

```
_appDbContext.OrderBy(x => x.MinSaleAmount)
                      .LastOrDefault(x => x.MinSaleAmount < salesTot);
```

Ok what this is saying is

Order the sales amount like you have in your table. Filter out anything above that sales amount, and choose the last one.

If `salesTot` is higher then the last items in the list, it will return the last item in the list. if it is less than the minimum it will return null.

The confusion here was basically the concept if minimum sales amount, to be a G02 they cannot make less than 25000, or they are G01. However there is no upper limit. Though there is a finite lower limit

Comment: hi @TheGeneral let me check this one. Thanks for replying, I will revert back with my observations; I suppose this portion   '.FirstOrDefault(x => salesTot >= x.grade_minsaleamount);'       should do the trick of checking which range the salesAmount falls within;

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury yes as long as its ordered

Comment: there is a trouble here. If sales is higher than the highest value of 'MinSaleAmount' from those ranges, it gives erroneous results. For eg. a guy who made sale of 73000 suppose, still gives G01 as grade whereas IT SHOULD BE G05!

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury hrm ok i see your problem, give me a couple of hours and ill make an edit

Comment: thanks for replying. This portion .LastOrDefault(x => x.MinSaleAmount >= 100), you mean .LastOrDefault(x => x.MinSaleAmount >= 15000) right, ie the minimum value available.... A bit confused about that portion.. about the '100' ..

Comment: ohh okkay,  @TheGeneral, I see....  yes the value of salesTot actually; let me try it out. I will revert back with my progress/observations; thanks to you again,

Comment: nah @TheGeneral, not happening. In cases where the saleTot is very high ie higher than 65000 only in those cases it gives correct gradation. In other cases it if not doing so. I have added my actual data from my app so it is easier to understand and updated my question. So, when saleTot is like 96000 or 125000 or such a high value (ie higher than highest possible value) only in those cases it gives accurate measure, ie A+.
: ((    what to do?    I dabbled around with FirstOrDefault, LastOrDefault, SingleOrDefault, OrderBy etc.... but no.....

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury i finally understood what you wanted (i think)

Comment: yes correct @TheGeneral, there is no upper limit, it can be as high as possible. Though, there are fixed and clearly defined lower limits for the different grades; that's making it complex.! yes, so s guy who made 27500 bucks will fall within grade D, not grade C. similarly all values above 65000 naturally become A+ grade!

Comment: yes, this works just perfectly @TheGeneral. For all cases. For high values exceeding highest value of 65000 as well as low values below 15000 and any values in between.